# Git added git HEAD and repo info to files

Tags: php, git, push, syntax-error

I have looked around and can't seem to find an actual solution. I've found one or two examples of people with similiar issues but no reasoning to why it happened. Before I show the issue, let me explain what I did:

1. Pushed a commit from my dev server to the repo to use on my local machine
2. Checked the dev site and for some reason it now was broken with php errors everywhere

For some reason when I pushed the files it added the following to 20 different files at random locations:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
$config['debug'] = '1';
>>>>>>> origin/master
```

The `$config` variables are mine but for some reason git shoved content into my files. Any idea why this happened and how to keep it from happening again?

Comment: These are merge conflicts. You must have accidentally added a file with conflicts instead of resolving them.

Comment: Interesting, I followed all of the error advice that it popped up as far as stashing different ones, etc. And some are on files that I don't even touch as their in the core of the CMS I use. Thanks for the info on the merge conflicts though. Is there a git log that I could provide that might help in identifying the culprit?

Comment: you could `git blame` one of the affected files to see when the change was introduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
$config['debug'] = '1';
>>>>>>> origin/master
```

This is unmerged files that you've added to your commit without solving a conflicts.

> Any idea why this happened and how to keep it from happening again?

Perhaps you did pull and git merges upstream commit with your commit. Or you just unfinished your manually merge process.

To keep it from happening again you should better notices a messages from git like this one:

```
Auto-merging roses.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in roses.txt
```

Then merge conflicts by yourself and add files to the stage.

Anyway, take a look at [this](http://blog.wuwon.id.au/2010/09/painless-merge-conflict-resolution-in.html) article or [question about merging conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git), it could be helpful.